# ¿Como ocultar el texto y su radio button, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo estos 3 radio buttons:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
      <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="2">
      <span class="item-media">
        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="item-inner">
        <span class="item-title">Recoger en Centro de Negocio</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
      <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1" checked>
      <span class="item-media">
        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="item-inner">
        <span class="item-title">Envío a Domicilio Normal</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="sucursalesCorreos">
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
      <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1">
      <span class="item-media">
        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="item-inner">
        <span class="item-title">Entregar en Sucursal de Correos</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pero debo realizar una validación que me permita ocultar o mostrar el `<li>` que tiene el texto **Envió a Domicilio Normal**

Es decir existirá una variable `Cod_emp` que si es igual a 5 se debe ocultar de lo contrario mostrar.

Comment: No puedes ponerle ids a los otros `<li>`?

Comment: ¿Dónde está tu código? ¿Dónde te has quedado atorado? Aquí tienes una documentación sobre .hide() jQuery http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

No se si te refieres a esto pero vamos allá. Lo que he entendido es que si el empleado es el número 5, no muestra el listado, de los contrario, lo muestra. Aquí tienes el código. Esto es un ejemplo sencillo con un botón que comprueba el valor del input. Si es diferente de 5, lo muestra, de lo contrario, lo oculta. No se si te vale para hacerte una idea de como lo puedes hacer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#boton").on('click',function(){
  var prueba1 = $("#input").val();
      if(prueba1 != 5){
        $("#sucursalesCorreos").show();
      }else
      {
        $("#sucursalesCorreos").hide();
      }
 });
});
```

```css
#sucursalesCorreos{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(159, 143, 241);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" value="">
<button id="boton">Click</button>

<div id="sucursalesCorreos">Div a esconder</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

solo cambias tu valor o `Cod` y es se oculta o muestra

```js
var Cod=4;
if(Cod===5){
  $("#envio_DN").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
else{
  $("#envio_DN").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>lista1</li>
  <li id="envio_DN">
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
      <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1" checked>
      <span class="item-media">
        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="item-inner">
      <span class="item-title">Envío a Domicilio Normal</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>lista3</li>
</ul>
```